# Jersey with Jetty hard time

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I can't run up my RESTful service with embedded Jetty 7 and Jersey. When I call my simple hello test I get:

```
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message
body writer for     Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String,
and MIME media type text/plain was    not found
```

I saw errors similar posted here on SO, but it was for custom classes, and mine is for just `String`. Any hints? My init server code:

```
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    ServletContainer container = new ServletContainer();
    ServletHolder h = new ServletHolder(container);
    h.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "api");
    context.addServlet(h, "/res/*");
```

And dependances:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.6.v20100715</version>
</dependency>
```

Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange `jersey-server` to :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
   <version>1.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```